# Could not load file or assembly 'Atalasoft.dotImage.Ocr' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, dotimage

I am developing a 64bit application using C# (Visual Studio 2010) and DotImage DLLs (AtalaSoft). When I build the application, I get the error message below:

'Could not load file or assembly 'Atalasoft.dotImage.Ocr' or one of its dependencies. 
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'

However, when I change the application to x86, the application builds just fine (does not have any errors).

I have tried the solution on http://www.atalasoft.com/KB/article.aspx?id=10149 to no avail.

Any ideas how I can resolve the error?

Comment: The documentation states that you do not need to compile 64bit to run it on x64. Do you have specific needs for compiling for x64?

Comment: Yes. I referenced the x64 bit dlls and when I compile, I get the error above. No problems when compiling using x86 though...

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that they provide built DLLs for either architecture.  Have you checked to make sure you are only referencing the x64 one?